# aws for pre-landing page

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using aws for my pre-landing page. **Namecheap/Godaddy** for a domain name, **S3** to store the landers, **Cloudfront** for **CDN** and Route 53 for DNS.

**Problem is**, I have my lander available in S3. It is a URL: *https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/janicko.xyz/index.html*. But it is not available on the site *myweb.xyz*, which is what I like to have. When I type janicko.xyz, I receive an error 403 (bad request).

**S3 is set-up as follow:**

*Static website hosting:* index.html

*Permissions:* Block of all public access is OFF

*Bucket policy:*

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::janicko.xyz/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

*Public Permissions:* "Grant public read access to this object(s)"

**Cloudfront is set up as follow:**

*Default root object:* index.html

*SSL certificate:* Default (I asked for SSL certificate, but did not receive a positive answer)

*Origin Domain Name and Path is:* janicko.xyz.s3.amazonaws.com

**Route 53 is set up as follow:**

I have added 4 records. www IP4, IP4 (without www), www IP6, and IP6 without www.
Alias target for all four records is domain name from Cloudfront (*longnumber.cloudfront.net*)
In route 53 one record now has type NS. There are four values. These are added to Godaddy/Namecheap DNS to point to my AWS.

When I tried to do the DNS check (dnschecker.org), everything was confirmed as OK.

Any idea, what am I doing wrong? I not very techie and everything described in any step by step guides was followed. So this result is confusing me.

Comment: Is `myweb.xyz` the actual domain? If not, please provide the real one.

Comment: The actual domain is janicko.xyz. But it happened to another also.

Comment: Did you configure your CloudFront distribution to accept the `janicko.xyz` domain via the "Alternate Domain Names (CNAMEs)" field? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/CNAMEs.html

Comment: For that, I need to have a custom SSL certificate. And I do not have it yet.

Comment: Now I checked the Certificate Manager once again. I see for my sites janicko.xyz and *.janicko.xyz, I have the status of "Success". So why am I not able to add custom certificate in Cloudfront (it is grayed)?

Comment: Even CNAME in route 53 is filled already.